# Public Developer's Story 404

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, developer-story, 404-not-found

I setup my developer's story and made it **public** but when I try to open it using an **"incognito"** browser to simulate someone other than me or someone who is not logged in to view it I get a **404 error**.

https://stackoverflow.com/cv-beta/tjb

[image: public developer story 404]

I'm using the link from the "Story View" on the edit cv page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is expected. During the private beta, only beta users are able to see developer stories.

Thank you for your report <3

Comment: Whoops, my bad, thanks for pointing that out.  Maybe there should be a warning about this somewhere?

Comment: Can we add a note or something about this? I thought it was a bug too, the "Public" right above it confused me too (I get that it's related to the other block but still, it says public and it isn't) Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/r5LeLmF.png

Comment: It says "Visibility: Public" ... that means "expected behaviour"?!

Comment: It means "private beta". It will become public once everyone has access to Developer Stories.

Comment: @ria4 Is there an ETA for this or a way to keep up to date with progress? My "private beta" developer story is now much more up to date (because I hadn't realised it was private) than my original CV - and there's no way that I can see to export the data back to the original careers site.

Comment: I'd like to second that this behavior was unexpected / confusing.  A simple text change of "Visibility: Public" to "Visibility: Beta Users" would clarify immensely.  The tooltip shown on hover also says "Visible to everyone".  I fiddled for 15 minutes convinced I'd configured privacy wrong.

Comment: @jamesc It looks like the old CV can still be updated with by clicking the "Edit CV" tab.  Syncing data between the two versions doesn't seem possible though.

Comment: @jamesc sorry it took me so long to get back to you, missed the ping somehow. Based on feedback we got from the community (yours included) we recently changed a lot of things around story visibility. Changes should be up next week. I'll make the copy changes suggested by tedmiston in the meantime - looks like a simple yet effective way to clarify the behavior while we're still on private beta.

Comment: @ria4 Thanks for you message. Where can I see a list of the changes made? I'm still confused because the profile page says "Share your Developer Story" and has status "public" but the URLs lead to 404s - so I can't share at all really :(

Comment: @jamesc I updated the tooltip copy to "Visible to beta users" instead of "Visible to everyone". Hopefully that will make visibility less confusing while we're not on public beta yet.